# Remove previous content when new one is rendered through a condition (React)

Tags: reactjs

I have a navbar that uses eventKeys to switch between the buttons

```
const CustomNav = ({ active, onSelect, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Nav
      {...props}
      activeKey={active}
      onSelect={onSelect}
      style={{ marginBottom: "15px" }}>
      <Nav.Item eventKey='all'>All</Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item eventKey='movies'>Movies</Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item eventKey='shows'>Shows</Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item eventKey='people'>People</Nav.Item>
    </Nav>
  );
};
```

I did this:

```
const Content = () => {
  if (this.state.active === "all") {
    return (
      <div>
        {trending.results &&
          trending.results.map((i) => (
            <React.Fragment key={i.id}>
              <p>{i.title}</p>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  } else if (this.state.active === "movies") {
    return (
      <div>
        {trendingMovies.results &&
          trendingMovies.results.map((i) => (
            <React.Fragment key={i.id}>
              <p>{i.title}</p>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Called it here:

```
    return (
      <div className='Home'>
        <FlexboxGrid justify='center'>
          <Panel bordered header='Trending today!'>
            <CustomNav
              className='customNav'
              appearance='subtle'
              active={active}
              onSelect={this.handleType}
            />
            <Content />
            <Pagination
              {...this.state}
              style={{ marginTop: "15px" }}
              maxButtons={5}
              size='sm'
              pages={totalPages}
              activePage={this.state.activePage}
              onSelect={this.handlePage}
            />
          </Panel>
        </FlexboxGrid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

To display the correct data for each tab, but when I'm on the movies tab it shows all the data from the first "all" tab + data on the "movies" tab. I wanna show each data individually corresponding to the correct tab which is controlled by "this.state.active". Tried a switch statement too and that did not work

Comment: Can you add some code to show how you are calling the Content method? It will be helpful you could show us some actual output and expected output.

Comment: Console and check the state `this.state.active` value

Comment: @sabbir.alam I'm calling it as a component (how you would usually do in React).

Comment: @UKS this.state.active is changing, but when actually rendering content when I switch active from 'all' to 'movies' it shows me 'all' + 'movies' data

Answer (score 0):

you are using the arrow syntax

```
const Content = () => { ... }
```

and also using `this.state` variable in your code !!!

if you want to use `this.state`, then you want to use the class syntax, like

```
class Content extends React.Component { ... }
```

but don't mix the two styles.

what you are probably wanting to do is to send the `active` variable as a prop

try:

```
const Content = ({active}) => {
    if (active === 'all') {
        return (...)
    } else if (active === 'movies') {
        return (...)
    }
    return null
}
```

and where you are calling the component you send the active value in as a prop

```
<Content active={active} />
```

Note also that you are using the variables `trending` and `trendingMovies` and it is unclear where those come from, you may need to send those via props also.

Now you can also leave the `if..else` logic outside of your Content component like so

```
const Content = ({myTrending}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {myTrending.results &&
         myTrending.results.map((i) => (
            <React.Fragment key={i.id}>
              <p>{i.title}</p>
            </React.Fragment>
         ))}
      </div>
    );
}
```

and then where you call that component  you have

```
<Content 
    myTrending={active === 'all' ? trending : trendingMovies}
/>
```

Comment: First of all, I am already using a class based component. How would I use state if I wasn't? I already have a navbar that uses the active keyword as a keyevent and switches between tabs I'm trying to show each data to the correct tab per example if I'm in the all tab it should show the data for everything. In my case, it shows the data on the 'all' tab, but also shows the same data on the movies tab + the actual correct movies data. I'm trying to show the matching thing for each tab

Comment: You are not giving enough of your code to see what you are trying to do, if you want to use the state with an arrow syntax, you need to use the `useState` hook, as the `this` keyword will not refer to the component

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `active` and other variables as props to the Content component, since it doesn't access them otherwise:

```
const Content = ({active, trending=[], trendingMovies=[]}) => {
  if (active === "all") {
    return (
      <div>
        {trending.results.map((i) => (
            <React.Fragment key={i.id}>
              <p>{i.title}</p>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  } else if (active === "movies") {
    return (
      <div>
        {trendingMovies.results.map((i) => (
            <React.Fragment key={i.id}>
              <p>{i.title}</p>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

```
 return (
      <div className='Home'>
        <FlexboxGrid justify='center'>
          <Panel bordered header='Trending today!'>
            <CustomNav
              className='customNav'
              appearance='subtle'
              active={active}
              onSelect={this.handleType}
            />
            <Content active={this.state.active} trending={this.state.trending} trendingMovies={this.state.trendingMovies} />
            <Pagination
              {...this.state}
              style={{ marginTop: "15px" }}
              maxButtons={5}
              size='sm'
              pages={totalPages}
              activePage={this.state.activePage}
              onSelect={this.handlePage}
            />
          </Panel>
        </FlexboxGrid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check that active, trending and trendingMovies actually have their values set on the state.

Comment: Yes their values are retrieved from a get request through my redux reducer

Comment: Also check that `active` is active either `all` or `movies` inside `Content`.

Comment: yeah I'm logging the active data it's changing but not the content, only solution here seems to be to completely make a new page and use the router